# How can I model a weak entity in ER to have two keys from the same strong entity?

Tags: entity-relationship

Long story short, I need to model some sort of football database. A match is identified by a date and by the two teams that compete. I have a strong entity called Team, the question is how can I model so the match entity (which I suspect will be a weak entity) has two dependents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your match entity will have three fields:date, team1, team2.

The primare key of the match entity will be like:
primarykey(date, team1, team2)

```
Create table Match(
  date datetime not_null,
  team1 int not_null,
  team2 int not_null,
  primary_key(date, team1, team2),
  foreign key (team1) references Team(id),
  foreign key (team2) references Team(id)
)
```

Comment: My thoughts exactly, but how will it look when modelled with ER-notations?

Comment: You mean with the Entity Relation Model?

When you DRAW squares and arrows?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, then what you want is something like this. The problem is that there a different notations for this. I hope this helps you.

[image: ER Model]

Comment: I think I may have solved it anyway, but I appreciate your help!